# Fix position in IE for mat-expansion-indicator

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, material-design

So, I have looked at related posts about the Angular/Material `mat-expansion-indicator`, how to change its position and manipulate it in other ways with `CSS`. So, I was able to move it from the right to the left in the expansion panel header. I have some basic knowledge with Angular (6, 7), but I still have a lot to figure out. In IE (10/11), which I have to support for a little while longer, the `mat-expansion-indicator` is completely shifted out of whack. It doesn't even pretend to be lined up with the text.

[image: IE: Expansion panel without any "IE only" CSS.]

Now, I realize that some would call the following `CSS` work-around a hack, and I get it. However, I need to get this to work, and here's what works, for starters:

```css
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    // IE styles here
    top: 10px !important;
}
```

That gives me nicely lined up carets in the expansion panel header, just like the other web browsers.

[image: Expansion panel header in IE with IE-only CSS]

As you can see from the screenshot, this works only for collapsed expansion panels. And that's where I have been stuck almost all day so far: How can I target an expanded `mat-expansion-indicator` with `CSS`? I have tried some `::after` things that I have seen in other posts, but nothing seems to stick. I tried to mess with `CSS` transformations, but that caused all kinds of issues.

Right now, I know that the expanded `mat-expansion-indicator` needs to have a `top` position of `24px` to line up decently. I just don't know how to access that expanded `mat-expansion-indicator`. Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you shouldn't do things like that with pixels. You could give the div `display: flex;` and then give `align-items: center;` This way everything is vertically centred no matter what the height of the div is.

It would look like this:

```css
div {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```